# Securing API authentication requests with React & NextJS

Tags: reactjs, api, security, next.js

I'm building a React / NextJS web application which consumes one headless Drupal API & another NodeJS API.

To make requests to the NodeJS API it requires an authentication token which is generated by passing two unique user values and one constant value (changes per consumer but I'm only building one consumer so constant to me) to the relevant endpoint and returns an access & refresh token.

What would be the best way to handle this securely? Just making the requests from the client will make it all visible in the dev tools and some requests won't be able to be made by NextJS at page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the backend:

Don't handle the authentication tokens on the frontend at all. Use the backend to set a cookie with the options `httpOnly` (this disables the access from the javascript side) and use the newer `someOrigin` (only the newest browser supports it) to prevent CSRF.

For a good introduction into this topic, you should read the following article: https://medium.com/@jcbaey/authentication-in-spa-reactjs-and-vuejs-the-right-way-e4a9ac5cd9a3